# GetFACL/SetFACL from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, acl

I need to manage directory permissions via [ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) on a linux box from PHP where we have setup a Windows share and mounted it on the local linux box. I'm looking for a way to get and set permissions for the directory within a PHP class that I can then use to interface with the frontend. I found some work by [subutux back in 2010](http://blog.subutux.be/2010/02/03/acl-viewer-in-php/) - but not sure about the execution:

```
function getfacl($f){
  //inital parsing
  $facl = shell_exec("getfacl $f");
  $facl_ = explode("\n",$facl);
  //print_r($facl_);
  foreach ($facl_ as $line){
    // Getting creator
    if (!preg_match("/^# file.*/",$line) && preg_match("/^#.*/",$line)){
    $facl_rule = explode(": ",$line);
    //print_r($facl_rule);
      if ($facl_rule[0] == "# owner"){
      $facl_output['owner'] = $facl_rule[1];
      } else if ($facl_rule[0] = "# group"){
      $facl_output['group'] = $facl_rule[1];
      }
  }
  return $facl_output;
}
```

So, I have a two questions:

1. Does the above get the job done for GetFACL and how would I go about running a SetFACL command?
2. Are there any other known libraries for working with linux ACL from PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't receive any responses on this one. I eventually got it working so I thought I would post in case anyone else ran into similar issue.

What we ended up doing was created a shared mount on the linux box from the MS directory on the external sever. From there we have rights via a user to that mount. I then used the library [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), specifically the [ssh2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) component and ran shell commands to retrieve and run the ACL.

For example, here is a view of the php for retrieving the getfacl:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('location');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
   exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('ssh shared_mount_user@shared_mount_domain getfacl -R /folder/folder/file);
```

I can run all of my directory commands in similar function such as setfacl, ls, rm, etc.

I can also retrieve and parse the getfacl into specific parts like so:

```
$facl = $ssh->exec('ssh shared_mount_user@shared_mount_domain getfacl /folder/folder');
$facl_ = explode("\n",$facl);
$users_array = array(); 
foreach ($facl_ as $line){
     if (!preg_match("/^# file.*/",$line) && preg_match("/^#.*/",$line)){
     $facl_rule = explode(": ",$line);
     if ($facl_rule[0] == "# owner"){
        $facl_output['owner'] = $facl_rule[1];
     } else if ($facl_rule[0] = "# group"){
        $facl_output['group'] = $facl_rule[1];
     }
  }
  if (!preg_match("/^#/",$line) && preg_match("/^user:/",$line)){
     $facl_user_rule = explode(":",$line);
     array_push($users_array,$facl_user_rule);
  }
}
```

In the end, I wrote a class that puts all of these into nice little instances so I can do something like `echo $FileManager->get_contents_array($ssh, $location);` that will simply run a ssh `ls` command and parse the hierarchy to display in a directory UI.

Hope this helps out someone.